# ¿Como saco los datos de un objeto JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(s) para ser ocupados como valor de una variable?

Tags: c#, json

Tengo la siguiente cadena de ejemplo en string dentro de una aplicacion C#:

```
string json={"success":56,"msg_error":"credenciales no reconocidas"}
```

Que recibo de un servicio web. Lo que necesito es sacar el valor de "success" y asignarlo a una variable para posterior uso. He intentado con

```
var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
var id = results['success'];
if (id == 0){
    MessageBox.Show("OK");
}else{
    MessageBox.Show("Nada"); 
}
```

Que esta dentro de un boton de un form de C#, Pero el compilador de visual detecta un error que al buscarlo no aparece.
¿Que es lo que estoy haciendo mal, o porque no puede reconocerse?

Answer (score 1):

En este caso como ya deserialiste el `Json` a una clase, puedes hacer uso directo de sus propiedades:

```
var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
var id = results.success;
if (id == 0){
    MessageBox.Show("OK");
} else {
    MessageBox.Show("Nada"); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando Json.net puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
dynamic json = {"success": 56, "msg_error": "credenciales no reconocidas"}

 if (json.success == 0)
 {
     MessageBox.Show("OK");
 } else {
     MessageBox.Show(json.msg_error);
 }
```